# Auto resizing controls when content changes in winforms using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, tablelayoutpanel

I am using the `TableLayoutPanel` object in my `Form` and sizing the window auto sizes my controls very nicely but I have a `Label` inside one of the panels that holds the most of the text the user sees. I want the form to grow if the text increases.

So if the text increases, because the object auto-size property is set, the object will increase and as its anchored (L, R, T,& B) to the panel it wraps the text nicely. The panel itself is set to auto size and so I want this to increase automatically and then the form should grow automatically as well.

If I increase the window size manually all of the text becomes visible as the layout panel increases in size but I want it to increase when the text changes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have your `AutoSizeMode` set to Grow and Shrink

Comment: Yes, has no effect (was on grow only). The panel row size property needs to be set to 100% and the other row to auto size.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `AutoSize` property of the `Form`, `TableLayoutPanel` , and `Label` to `true`, Then set the `AutoSizeMode` property of the `Form` to `GrowAndShirnk`.

Comment: It still wont work. When the label increases because of the extra text I expected the panel to increase because of the auto size property and then a cascade of auto sizing but nothing.

Comment: Hmmm, I added `TableLayoutPanel` to my form, inside one of its panel I added a `Label` then I did what i mentioned and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the resize event of the form after you've changed the text of the label.